# Range function to count results

Tags: python

So I have little problem.
I have 2 locations and sports day results:

```
location1 = [401, 604, 547, 700, 722, 845, 621, 490, 800, 700]
location2 = [900, 0, 333, 803, 838, 400, 467, 488, 432, 700]
```

and I have to get results that way, that only the best is shown. Also in the end there have to be sum of these results.
Final result should look like this:

```
[900, 604, 547, 803, 845, 621, 490, 800, 700]
Sum: 7148
```

All I get is location with best overall score and sum, not the best results from each. Anyone have ideas?

Comment: [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) both the locations lists together and find the [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) of each pair either with list comprehension or [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), then [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) them all together.

Answer (score 3):

```
best_results = [max(x,y) for x,y in zip(location1, location2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
max_results = [max(item) for item in zip(location1,location2)]
total = sum(max_results)
```

Or just for sport:

```
max_results = [max(location1[index],location2[index]) for index in range(0, len(location1))]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also work.

```
best_results = list(map(lambda x: max(location1[x], location2[x]), range(len(location1))))
total = sum(best_results)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
results = [max(x,y) for x,y in zip(location1, location2)]
total = sum(results)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.